# VB.NET - For Each loop not changing elements in an array of class

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class, for-loop, foreach

I'm using an array of class; the class is very simple and only contains one element. The class is declared as follows:

```
Class Cell
    Public Info As Int16
End Class
```

The array:

```
Dim Maze(11, 15) As Cell
```

I want to use a simple sub to set the .Info variable for every element to 15, but I realise I have to create the elements first. I tried using a For Each loop as follows, but it didn't work, when the loop completed everything was still set to nothing:

```
For Each e As Cell In Maze
    If e Is Nothing Then
        e = New Cell
    End If
Next
```

I'm not concerned about the correct solution: I used a regular For loop and this accomplishes everything I want done...

```
For a = 0 To Maze.GetUpperBound(0)
    For b = 0 To Maze.GetUpperBound(1)
        Maze(a, b) = New Cell
        Maze(a, b).Info = Maze(a, b).Info Or 15
    Next
Next
```

...but I'd like to know why the For Each loop didn't work in the first place, as I'm sure there's some fundamental principle I'm missing here.

Comment: In a for each loop you cannot affect the variable being iterated. VB.NET shouldn't allow you to write this code; although banning is not the VB.NET style :)

Comment: Ahh okay. Maybe VB.net is a bit too permissive...

Answer (score 6):

The reason the `For Each` loop did not work is because within the `For Each` construct, the local variable (in your case `e`) is not a reference, but rather a copy; thus your `New Cell` has no consequence on your array of `Cell`.

Comment: Actually, this is one of the consequences from VB.NET being so permissive. C# does not allow this configuration. Being permissive is fine but some times might be confusing for the programmer; in this case is logical assuming that the value of e is actually being changed.

Comment: Great point @varocarbas - I did not realize that C# did not even allow it until I just tried it in code.

Comment: Oh wow, I had never realised. Thank you! I've probably made this mistake many times before.

Comment: @LeoKing - If you feel this answer was helpful, then feel free to accept the answer. Good luck to you.